# How to detect if the machine is idle, no values coming from the server for 15s?

Tags: jquery, html, websocket

I have websocket client and server. I want to detect if the machine is idle for 15s (as in no data is coming from the server) from the client (used jQuery for the client). If no data is coming I want to popup.And again it should check this for 15s and so on.

I have used 'setTimeout'

```
setTimeout(function() {
    if (data == 0) {
        $('div#popup2').show()
    }
}, 15000);
```

But this will trigger only if they are 0 if data ==1 and the machine is idle it will not show the popup in 15s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  `clearTimeout` on else condition like below.

```js
var data = 0; // Change value to 1 if you want to see change. 
var tID;
$('#popup2').hide();
$('#popup1').hide();
if (data == 0)
  tID = setTimeout(function() {
    $("div#popup2").show()
  }, 1500);
else {
  clearTimeout(tID); // Else condition goes here whatever you want to do
  $("div#popup1").show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id='popup2'>Your Pop UP</div>
</div>
<div id='popup1'>Show Test Div</div>
```